# Обработка динамических ссылок в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

По API получаю HTML контент. В контенте есть ссылки по примеру:

```
<a href="/path/request_name">Ссылка</a>
```

Как методами JS в React застопить переход по такой ссылке, извлечь `request_name` и вывести в консоль по нажатию на ссылку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Событие ловите и делаете preventDefault()

```
a.addEventListener("click", (e) => {    e.preventDefault()
```

Далее что вам нужно

Answer (score 1):

Прицепите к `<a>` onClick и в обработчике выведите синтаксически обработанное содержание атрибута href - `console.log(event.target.getAttribute('href').split('/').reverse()[0])`